# Drupal preprocess_page variable passed to commerce-product-title.tpl.php does not load

Tags: templates, variables, drupal-7

I pass a variable in preprocess_page to the template files, so I think.

```
$vars['merk']=$merk;
```

It works fine when I call the variable in page.tpl.php . But when I call that variable in commerce-product-title.tpl.php it does not load, it returns null. I cannot find how to pass that variable to this tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that template is only used when displaying a product, which is a different entity to a page.

Try altering the vars in the product hook instead:

```
function hook_preprocess_commerce_product(&$vars) {
  $vars['merk']=$merk;
}
```